# JSF RichFaces - How to show a rich:modalPanel when page loaded?

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml, richfaces

That's exactly what I am looking for ... I need to show a rich:modalPanel automatically when the page has ended loading.

This is my approach so far:

MAIN.XHTML

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopUp(){
        if(#{rich:element('popUpAltaTrenesEstaciones')}.value == 'true'){

            #{rich:component('idAltaPlantillasTrenesEstacionesPop')}.show(); 
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

.........

```
<a4j:include id="popUp" viewId="AltaPlantillasTrenesEstacionesPopUp.xhtml" />
```

.....

```
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
     <h:inputText id="popUpAltaTrenesEstaciones"
     value="#{altaPlantillasTrenesEstaciones.showPopUp}"
     style="display:none;" />
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

BACKING BEAN. JAVA

```
    private boolean showPopUp;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
     ...
    setShowPopUp(true);
}
```

POPUP.XHTML

```
    <rich:modalPanel id="idAltaPlantillasTrenesEstacionesPop" height="200"
    width="400" rendered="true">

    <a4j:form>
            ........
           </a4j:form>
     </rich:modalPanel>
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG??? DO I NEED TO ADD ANYTHING ELSE?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

There is 'showWhenRendered' attribute or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call the function `openPopup()` you have declared ...

Comment: How do I call that function? What's the trigger event??

I've already tried this

      <body onload="openPopUp()"></body>

with no luck...